# parsing K8s yaml spec into client-go data structures

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I wrote some code but it doesn't work, it seems that client-go doesn't support parsing of K8s yaml spec into client-go data structures, could anyone tell me how to do it.

```golang
func GetDeploymentFromYamlString(str string) (*apps.Deployment, error) {
    decode := scheme.Codecs.UniversalDeserializer().Decode
    obj, _, err := decode([]byte(str), nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return obj.(*apps.Deployment), nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `github.com/ghodss/yaml` package to unmarshal the deployment yaml.

Try as following:

```golang
import "github.com/ghodss/yaml"

func GetDeploymentFromYamlString(str string) (*apps.Deployment, error) {
        deploy := new(apps.Deployment)
        if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), deploy); err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        return deploy, nil
}
```